# Custom Application Errors - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, exception

I'm trying to handle Exceptions in a webapp where I'm working and works fine until I put on the url something like **"http://localhost:52183/Usuario/InsertarUsuario/89."** and display this error on visual studio:

> an exception of type system.web.httpexception occurred on system.web.dll but was not handle in user code.

[Show Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebdfh.jpg)

**What I'm trying to do?**

If page doesn't exist display a 404 page

in other case, display a generic error.

***Code In Global.asax.vb***

```
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub

Protected Sub Application_Error(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim httpContext = DirectCast(sender, MvcApplication).Context
    Dim httpEx = TryCast(ex, HttpException)

    Response.Clear()


    If (httpEx Is Nothing Or httpEx.Message = "") Then
        httpEx = New HttpException(500, "Error interno de servidor", ex)
        Response.Redirect("~/Error/PeticionInvalida")
    End If

    If (TypeOf ex Is HttpException) Then

        If (httpEx.GetHttpCode = "404") Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/NoEncontrado")

        Else
            Response.Redirect("~/Error/PeticionInvalida")
        End If
    End If
    Server.ClearError()

End Sub

End Class
```

What I'm doing wrong? or how I would handle this errors?

Thank you in advance for the information you could give me.

Comment: What is the value of `ex`?

Comment: @mason its values is {""}. The the all object could see it in this [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AuJkZBtgExtkhEKXD0y7AwB1si2E)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `httpErrors` in web.config. It is an IIS setting so you have to put it in the `system.webserver` section of web.config. Since it is a IIS level setting it works well for catching 404's - especially those that don't match any of your routes.

Here is the code I use in my projects:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="400" path="/Error/BadRequest" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/NotAuthorized" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The `remove` tags are there to remove any inherited setting (e.g. from machine.config).

For each error code I'm simply executing a controller action. In my controller actions I also set the http response code accordingly so that the browser knows about the error - that's a good thing to do so that indexers like google don't index your error pages.

Update 7-4-2017: Here is the Error controller I use:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return View("Error");
    }

    public ViewResult BadRequest()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return View("BadRequest");
    }

    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View("NotFound");
    }

    public ViewResult NotAuthorized()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return View("NotAuthorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @jpishko, thanks for your answer and time, I tested your solution without effects. Could be how was created the site on IIS?

Comment: Make sure you remove the code you have in `Application_Error` especially the line `Server.ClearError()`. Also remove any `error` tags you have defined in `customErrors` in web.config. Set a breakpoint in your `ErrorController` to make sure it is being hit when you enter a non-existent URL which should result in a 404 error. I updated my answer to include the `ErrorController` I use.